# Sum of alternating reciprocals of logarithm of 2,3,4...

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, prime-numbers, convergence-divergence

How to determine convergence/divergence of this sum?

$$\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{\ln(n)}$$

Why cant we conclude that the sum $\sum_{k=2}^\infty (-1)^k\frac{k}{p_k}$, with $p_k$ the $k$-th prime, converges, since $p_k \sim k \cdot \ln(k)$ ?

Comment: [Alternating series test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series_test) (by the way, the sum should start at $n=2$ to avoid division by 0).

Comment: maybe you should start at $n=2$.

Comment: Provided the summation begins at $n=2$, this is an [alternating series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series#Alternating_series_test) hence the usual test gives the answer.

Comment: Re your second question, added later on: this is because the alternating series test requires the unsigned sequence to be **decreasing**. Even when $a_n\gt0$, $b_n\gt0$ and $a_n/b_n\to1$, $\sum(-1)^na_n$ and $\sum(-1)^nb_n$ may behave differently. Example: $a_n=\frac1{\sqrt{n}}$ and $b_n=\frac1{\sqrt{n}}+\frac{(-1)^n}n$.

Comment: I have a question. What are the values for those sums? And is there a page in OEIS in which that sums are computed?

Comment: @GuilleTejedor: for the value of the first sum, see [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2807691).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Alternating Series Test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series_test), which is a special case of the [Dirichlet Test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_test), ensures the convergence of the first series.

To apply the Dirichlet test to $k/p_k$, one would have to show that the sequence $\{k/p_k\}$ has bounded variation.  That is,
$$
\sum_{k=1}^\infty\left|\frac{k}{p_k}-\frac{k+1}{p_{k+1}}\right|<\infty\tag{1}
$$
I don't know if $(1)$ is true.

Comment: Using the **fact** that there are infinitely many prime pairs, we see that (1) diverges.  Now, perhaps someone should disprove (1) without using facts whose proofs are unknown.

Comment: @GEdgar: the contribution to $(1)$ from a prime pair would be $$\left|\frac{k}{p_k}-\frac{k+1}{p_k+2}\right| = \left|\frac{2k-p_k}{p_k(p_k+2)}\right|\sim\frac{1}{p_k}$$ However, this is only contributed over prime pairs. Is it known that the sum of the reciprocals of prime pairs converges or diverges?

Comment: @Sasha: insure and ensure are alternate spellings. There is more of a distinction in British English than in American English: "Our most recent evidence shows that the distinction between ensure and insure is made more often in British written English than in American written English, and a few commentators hold that insure is more common than ensure in American English."
("ensure, insure, assure," Merriam-Webster's Dictionary of English Usage, 1994)

Comment: The sum over reciprocals of all primes in arithemtic progression of length k, converges for all k.

Comment: @robjohn I see, I was not aware of this subtlety. Feel free to revert.

Comment: @mmm: Thanks. I was pretty sure that this was the case for $k>1$, but I didn't have a reference. The question remains as to why the infinitude of prime pairs belies $(1)$.

Comment: @Sasha: both are fine, and since "ensure" is better in Britain, there is no reason to revert. It was educational to look things up :-)

Answer (score 0):

You are correct.
The alternating series test suffices, no need to look at the dirichlet test.

Think about it, the sequence $|a|\rightarrow 0$ at $n\rightarrow\infty$, and decreases monotonically ($a_n>a_{n+1}$). That means that you add and remove terms that shrink to $0$. What you add you remove partially in the next term, and the terms shrink to 0. Eventually, **your sum converges** to a number but perhaps **extremely slowly**, but it will at least. If the terms didn't shrink to 0 but to a value $c$ or $a_{\infty}\rightarrow c$, then the series would be alternating around a value $middle\pm c$, hence not converge. We know this is not the case for $a_n=\frac{1}{p_n}$ (since there are infinitely many primes) and $a_n=\frac{1}{\log{n}}$, clearly $a_n$ tend to $0$ in both cases. For $a_n=\frac{n}{\log{n}}$, you are correct to assume that $\frac{p_n}{n}=\mathcal{O}\left(\log{n}\right)$. This means that $a_n=\frac{n}{p_n}=\mathcal{O}\left(\frac{1}{\log{n}}\right)\rightarrow 0$. From  ["The kth prime is greater than k(log k + log log k−1) for k ≥ 2"](https://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/1999-68-225/S0025-5718-99-01037-6/home.html), $\frac{p_n}{n}=\frac{1}{a_n}$ is stuck between

$\log n+\log\log n-1<\frac{p_n}{n}<\log{n}+\log\log n,$

then

$\frac{1}{\log n+\log\log n}<\frac{n}{p_n}<\frac{1}{\log{n}+\log\log n-1}.$

From the above inequality, we clearly see that the value $a_n=\frac{n}{p_n}$ is squished to $0$ by the bounds that vanish at infinity.
The sum accelerates so slowly that you may think that it alternates around a value $\pm c$, but this is not the case.

Similarly you can show that  $\sum_n \frac{(-1)^nn^{s}}{p_n }$ converges for $s\leq 1$, but will diverge for $Re(s)>1$.
And you have $\sum_n \frac{n^{s}}{p_n }$ converge if $Re(s)<0$. 
You see that modulating the sequence $a_n=\frac{n^{s}}{p_n }$ with $(-1)^n$ moves the region of convergence from $Re(s)<0$ to $Re(s)\leq 1$. The sum $\sum_n \frac{(-1)^nn^{s}}{p_n }$ is not differentiable for $
Re(s)=0$, therefore it should exhibit fractal like appearance on the imaginary line at the boundary. As it is for the [Prime Zeta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_zeta_function), $
Re(s)=0$ is a natural boundary for the derivative of $\sum_n \frac{(-1)^nn^{s}}{p_n }$. For the sum itself, it is a "softer" natural boundary!