# $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} (-1)^n \frac{1}{\log n}$ =?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

The alternating series, $s_n=\sum_{i=2}^{n} (-1)^i \frac{1}{\ln i}$, (with $\ln$ being the natural logarithm) converges for $n\to\infty$ which can be seen e.g. by the [Leibniz test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series_test). Can the limit be expressed in a finite closed expression of otherwise known constants?

I got interested while thinking about the values of the sine integral at integer multiples of $\pi$ where I suspect some relation.

Comment: I got 0.9243 when I typed it in wolframalpha. Many series don't have a known formula to express its sum.

Comment: @virtualize: Maybe with a bit more converged digits one could feed [Plouffes inverter](http://plouffe.fr/Simon%20Plouffe.htm)? Unf. I do not have maple access...

Comment: Inverse Symbolic Calculators do not find anything looking like $0.92429989722294$

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici: How many digits are trustful? marty cohens work suggests that for one digit you need to go to $n=10^{10}$.

Comment: Seems to be same as $\frac{162+\sqrt{13}-9\sqrt{10}}{180-10\sqrt{10}}$ up to ten decimal digits (gotten from inverse symbolic calculator), but then Maple shows different digits. Probably a coincidence...

Comment: No it does not have a known closed form. If it did then it would be a very well known result. It isn't so it hasn't.

Comment: @Winther: If that really is the case, that it would be well-known if it had, wouldn't it then make sense to give the beast a name and thus make it closed form?

Comment: @Sil: yes, the $11^\text{th}$ digits are different. It is a very close coincidence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doing my usual
pairing of even and odd,
if
$s_n
=\sum_{i=2}^{n} (-1)^i \dfrac{1}{\ln i}
$
then

$\begin{array}\\
s_{2n+1}
&=\sum_{i=2}^{2n+1} (-1)^i \dfrac{1}{\ln i}\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^{n} (\dfrac{1}{\ln (2i)}-\dfrac{1}{\ln (2i+1)})\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^{n} \dfrac{\ln (2i+1)-\ln (2i)}{\ln (2i)\ln (2i+1)}\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^{n} \dfrac{\ln (1+1/2i)}{\ln (2i)\ln (2i+1)}\\
&<\sum_{i=1}^{n} \dfrac{1/2i}{\ln (2i)\ln (2i+1)}\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^{n} \dfrac{1}{2i\ln (2i)\ln (2i+1)}\\
\end{array}
$

and this converges by comparison with
$\sum \dfrac1{i \ln^2 i}
$.

However,
this does converge
quite slowly.
The integral test,
using
$\int_2^n \dfrac{dt}{t\ln^2(t)}
=\dfrac1{\ln(2)}-\dfrac1{\ln(n)}
$
shows how slowly.
This, of course,
agrees with the result that
the sum of an alternating series
is between any two
consecutive partial sums.

For example,
if $n = 10^{10}$,
the error is about
$\dfrac1{2\ln(10^{10})}
=\dfrac1{20\ln(10)}
\gt .01
$.

If we apply
Euler's transform
(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Series_acceleration),

$\begin{array}\\
s
&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^n \dfrac{1}{\ln (n+2)}\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \dfrac{(-1)^n}{2^{n+1}}\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^k\binom{n}{k} \dfrac{1}{\ln (n-k+2)}\\
&\approx\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \dfrac{(-1)^n}{2^{n+1}}(\dfrac1{\ln(x+2)})^{(n)}|_{x=2}\\
&\approx\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \dfrac{(-1)^n}{2^{n+1}}((-1)^{n-1}\dfrac{(n-1)!}{(x+2)^n\ln(x+2)})|_{x=2}\\
&=-\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \dfrac{(n-1)!}{2^{3n+1}\ln(4)}\\
\end{array}
$

and this actually diverges!
(modulo any errors on my part)

That's enough for now.

Comment: I don't see how this answers the question. Speed of convergence is not relevant to the OP's question of whether there is a closed form.

Comment: I was doing what I could. My opinion is that any closed form would involve variations of the zeta function.

Comment: @martycohen: " involve variations of the zeta function" how comes?

Comment: There is no closed form (at least within my knowledge) but any evaluation of this with big Oh is possible.

Comment: @martycohen: Thank you for the great effort. Its quite useful to know the convergence behaviour for numerical calculations, esp, for estimating to how many digits it converged.

Comment: @Abr001am: "There is no closed form (at least within my knowledge)" got any evidence or just a gut feeling?

Comment: Intuitive deduction + I will answer this with my proposed approx, wait.

Comment: "wait": for how long?

Comment: Until the limit of the sum is determined within 0.000001.

Comment: I need to check my formulas before posting them i don't want to post *junk*

Comment: Never stopped me.

Answer (score 2):

Another comment, with no closed form at the end.

Start with the [polylogarithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm)
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty a^n n^{-s} = \mathrm{Li}_s(a)
$$
So that
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n n^{-s} = \mathrm{Li}_s(-1)
\\
\sum_{n=2}^\infty (-1)^n n^{-s} = 1 + \mathrm{Li}_s(-1)
$$
Integrate with respect to $s$ from $0$ to $+\infty$
$$
\sum_{n=2}^\infty (-1)^n \frac{1}{\log(n)}
= \int_0^\infty\big(1+\mathrm{Li}_s(-1)\big)ds \approx 0.92429989722293885595957018136
$$
Unfortunately, this also has no known closed form as far as I can find.

Comment: Very nice! We could also use the zeta function $$\int_0^\infty \left(1-(1-2^{1-x})\zeta(x) \right)dx$$

Answer (score 2):

This value can be computed using the [Euler-Maclaurin Sum Formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Maclaurin_formula).

We will start with
$$
\begin{align}
g_1(n)
&=\sum_{k=2}^n\frac1{\log(k)}\\
&=\,\scriptsize C_1+\operatorname{li}(n)+\frac1{2\log(n)}-\frac1{12n\log(n)^2}+\frac1{360n^3\log(n)^2}\left(1+\frac3{\log(n)}+\frac3{\log(n)^2}\right)\\
&\,\scriptsize -\,\frac1{15120n^5\log(n)^2}\left(12+\frac{50}{\log(n)}+\frac{105}{\log(n)^2}+\frac{120}{\log(n)^3}+\frac{60}{\log(n)^4}\right)\\[3pt]
&\,\scriptsize +\,O\!\left(\frac1{n^7\log(n)^2}\right)\tag1
\end{align}
$$
where $\operatorname{li}(n)$ is the [Logarithmic Integral Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithmic_integral_function), and
$$
\begin{align}
g_2(n)
&=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1{\log(2k)}\\
&\,\scriptsize =C_2+\frac12\operatorname{li}(2n)+\frac1{2\log(2n)}-\frac1{12n\log(2n)^2}+\frac1{360n^3\log(2n)^2}\left(1+\frac3{\log(2n)}+\frac3{\log(2n)^2}\right)\\
&\,\scriptsize -\,\frac1{15120n^5\log(2n)^2}\left(12+\frac{50}{\log(2n)}+\frac{105}{\log(2n)^2}+\frac{120}{\log(2n)^3}+\frac{60}{\log(2n)^4}\right)\\[3pt]
&\,\scriptsize +\,O\!\left(\frac1{n^7\log(n)^2}\right)\tag2
\end{align}
$$
To get the alternating series, we compute
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=2}^{2n}\frac{(-1)^k}{\log(k)}
&=2\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1{\log(2k)}-\sum_{k=2}^{2n}\frac1{\log(k)}\\
&=2g_2(n)-g_1(2n)\\[6pt]
&\,\scriptsize =2C_2-C_1+\frac1{2\log(2n)}-\frac1{8n\log(2n)^2}+\frac1{192n^3\log(2n)^2}\left(1+\frac3{\log(2n)}+\frac3{\log(2n)^2}\right)\\
&\,\scriptsize -\,\frac1{7680n^5\log(2n)^2}\left(12+\frac{50}{\log(2n)}+\frac{105}{\log(2n)^2}+\frac{120}{\log(2n)^3}+\frac{60}{\log(2n)^4}\right)\\[3pt]
&\,\scriptsize +\,O\!\left(\frac1{n^7\log(n)^2}\right)\tag3
\end{align}
$$
Note that the $\operatorname{li}(n)$ terms cancel.

We can use $(3)$ with $n=1000000$, or we can extend $(3)$ to contain all terms bigger than $O\!\left(\frac1{n^{11}}\right)$ and use $n=10000$. In either case, we get

$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=2}^\infty\frac{(-1)^k}{\log(k)}
&=2C_2-C_1\\
&=0.92429989722293885595957018135959005377331939789\tag4
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Sorry for stupid question but maybe I miss something: Where is the definition of $C_1$ and $C_2$?

Comment: The constant in $(3)$ is $2C_2-C_1$. We compute it by plugging large enough values of $n$ into the left and right sides. We don't need to compute them individually, the same as we don't need to compute $\operatorname{li}(n)$ because it cancels.